# How to access a value in an array level that exist multiple time?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
<lists>
   <id>1234</id>
   <listid>5</listid>
   <listname>MyList</listname>
</lists>
<fields>
   <id>1</id>
   <title>DayOfWeek</title>
   <value>Monday</value>
</fields>
<fields>
  <id>2</id>
  <title>Date</title>
  <value>15-07-2018</value>
</fields>
<fields>
  <id>3</id>
  <title>Year</title>
  <value>2018</value>
</fields>
```

How do I access the value 'Monday' in PHP?

I tried this:

```
return $response['fields']['value'];
```

But of course this doesn't work.

How to access the one that has id of 1, so I get the value 'Monday'?

Comment: That is not an array. That looks like and might be XML, but you haven't shown us anything about how you attempt to parse the XML. We can't help you without the code that you're actually using. Note that if `$response` is just a string containing XML, then you cannot access it as if it was an associative array because it is not, in fact, an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SimpleXML parser. It's part of the PHP Core from version 5.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
print($xml["field"]["value"]);
```

*I haven't run the code yet. So, please see the documentation rather than copying the above code.*

Reference[W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp)